# NodeJS/Express Server on Heroku, NextJS Client on Vercel, SocketIO Problem

Tags: node.js, heroku, socket.io, next.js, vercel

I’ve got a problem with my NextJS +  NodeJS + SocketIO setup and i wrap my head around it since days.

In development mode on my mac machine everything is fine but in production there is the problem.

The NodeJS server is hosted on Heroku and the NextJS client is hosted on Vercel.

Server:

```
require('dotenv').config()

// Packages
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const passport = require('passport')
const cookie = require('cookie')
const jwtDecode = require('jwt-decode')
const cors = require('cors')

// App
const app = express()

// Models
const User = require('./models/User')

// App Settings
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: '10mb', extended: true }))
app.use(express.json({ limit: '10mb', extended: true }))
app.use(passport.initialize())

// App Routes
app.use('/_admin', require('./routes/_admin'))
app.use('/auth', require('./routes/auth'))
app.use('/profile', require('./routes/profile'))
app.use('/posts', require('./routes/posts'))
app.use('/comments', require('./routes/comments'))
app.use('/search', require('./routes/search'))
app.use('/users', require('./routes/users'))

require('./utils/passport')(passport)

const db = process.env.MONGO_URI
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000

mongoose
  .connect(db, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('MongoDB Connected') // eslint-disable-line no-console

    const server = app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`)) // eslint-disable-line no-console
    const io = require('socket.io')(server)

    io.on('connection', async socket => {
      const decodedUser =
        socket.handshake.headers.cookie && cookie.parse(socket.handshake.headers.cookie).jwtToken
          ? jwtDecode(cookie.parse(socket.handshake.headers.cookie).jwtToken)
          : null

      if (decodedUser) {
        console.log(`${socket.id} -> ${decodedUser.username} -> connected`) // eslint-disable-line no-console

        const user = await User.findById(decodedUser.id)

        if (!user.sockets.includes(socket.id)) {
          user.sockets.push(socket.id)
          user.dateOnline = Date.now()
          user.isOnline = true
          user.save()
        }

        socket.on('disconnect', async () => {
          console.log(`${socket.id} -> ${decodedUser.username} -> disconnected`) // eslint-disable-line no-console

          const user = await User.findById(decodedUser.id)
          const index = user.sockets.indexOf(socket.id)
          user.sockets.splice(index, 1)

          if (user.sockets.length < 1) {
            user.isOnline = false
            user.dateOffline = Date.now()
          }

          user.save()
        })
      } else {
        console.log(`${socket.id} -> GUEST -> connected`) // eslint-disable-line no-console

        socket.on('disconnect', async () => {
          console.log(`${socket.id} -> GUEST -> disconnected`) // eslint-disable-line no-console
        })
      }
    })
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err)) // eslint-disable-line no-console
```

Client React Context:

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import io from 'socket.io-client'

const SocketContext = createContext()

export function useSocket() {
  return useContext(SocketContext)
}

export function SocketContextProvider({ children }) {
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    setSocket(io(process.env.NOIZE_APP_SERVER_URL))
  }, [])

  const defaultContext = { socket }
  return <SocketContext.Provider value={defaultContext}>{children}</SocketContext.Provider>
}

SocketContextProvider.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node
}
```

The hole React app is wrapped is this context-provider and as i said, on my localhost everything works fine.
The problem on the Heroku server is, that it is not receiving the cookie with my bearer jwt token from client in the SocketIO handshake. I’m lost right now and hope for help/hints/and so on…
Thank you very much =)

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem!

```
cookies.set('jwtToken', jwtToken, {
  path: '/',
  domain: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? 'localhost' : 'example.com'
})
```

The cookie needs the domain attribute in this case because the server runs on `api.example.com` and the client on `www.example.com`.